# How can I make the picture stored in smart card to be an image url for asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, winforms

I am a bit newbie in asp.net coming from c# winforms.
I just want to ask because I just can't call a picturebox in asp.net similar in how I do it in C# winforms.

This is what I do in C# winforms if I want to get the image from the card

```
Picturebox1.Image = smartcard.gmain.Member.Image;
```

Now this is very different in asp.net. Image url is the only way to display an image
How can I solve this?

Comment: How you are accessing the smart card? Is smart card available in server?

Comment: We don't access it in using any server. It is already saved inside the smart card.